# calculate the limitation

Tags: calculus, limits

I have encountered a limitation:
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_1^{1+h} \sqrt{x^2+8}dx}{h}$$
I wanted to use the L'Hopital rule, but to take the derivative of the integral?

Comment: Hint:  this looks a lot like a derivative.

Comment: I know it just the $\sqrt{x^2+8}$ but should we take the value 1 to calculate the limit?

Answer (score 2):

Let me call the following function $F:$

$$F\colon\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\colon t\mapsto F(t)=\int_1^t\sqrt{x^2+8}\text dx.$$

Then, the limit you're trying to calculate becomes

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_1^{1+h}\sqrt{x^2+8}\text dx}h=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{F(1+h)-F(1)}h.$$

If you still have problems continuing on your own, feel free to ask!

Comment: Hi, so actually by using the l'hopital rule in this case, since denominator and nominator both becomes 0 when $h \to 0$ it becomes: $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(1+h)}{1}=\sqrt{1+8}=3$?

Comment: You can also avoid L'Hopital and just invoke the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Not only that, but $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{F(1+h)-F(1)}h$ is _defined_ as $F'(1)$ (unless the limit doesn't exist), and you correctly identified this as $f(1)$ already.

Comment: So, yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a continuous $f$ and call $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$

Then $f(x)=F'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h$

Can you identify which is which is this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Mean value theorem, integrand is continuos.

$I(h):= (1/h) \int_{1}^{1+h}\sqrt{x^2+8}dx =$

$(1/h)h\sqrt{t^2+8},$  $1\le t \le (1+h)$

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} I(h) = $

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{t^2+8}$ , $1\le t\le 1+h.$

Can you take it from here?